# What does "M" mean when used as a class name prefix?

Tags: naming-conventions

I am maintaining an old C++/MFC code base where quite a few class names are prefixed with "M" (e.g. `MAdrSet`, `MDialogBase` etc.). So far I have been unable to figure out what this prefix means - there is no recognizable pattern to where the prefix does, or does not, appear.

I have been thinking of the MFC naming convention that prefixes class names with "C" (e.g. `CWnd`, `CDialog`), meaning "class". Does anyone know of a similar naming convention, possibly at home in the Windows/MFC world, for the "M" class name prefix?

Comment: @Jordão: Interesting idea, but I don't think so. While in some cases M = Mixin might be a good match (the `MDialogBase` example), most of the time the classes in question are at the bottom of the class hierarchy. Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: Another wild guess: I've seen old VB/VBA code where prefixes 'M' and 'C' were used to distinguish regular modules from class modules. Is there a chance that your codebase is a result of porting from VB to C++? In that case, classes whose names start with 'M' most likely would be singletons or would act like ones.

Comment: @Yarik No, there was never a port from VB. If porting from _really_ old code (1985) has been done, then it would have been from C or assembly code (even now there is a `MONEY` class written in assembly code that nobody dares to touch). Thanks for your suggestion, but the mystery remains :-)

Comment: The [module](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110264) reference seems about the closest to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that the "M" prefix to class names has been a private naming convention that was in force during some time in the past, but meanwhile has been put to a miserable and confused death by some of my copy-pasting predecessors.

The best guess I currently have is that the "M" prefix originally meant "implementation", versus the common "I" that stands for "interface". Since I wrote the question I have come across many more "M" classes, and at least some of them implement an interface with the same name (e.g. `MWriter` implements `IWriter`).